# How to update all Azure Powershell Az modules?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

The Azure Powershell Az module comes with an assortment of modules such as Az.Accounts, Az.Aks, etc. Is it possible to update all these Az.* modules at once?

Comment: Please see this: https://robertsmit.wordpress.com/2020/05/27/update-all-az-azure-powershell-modules-powershell-azure-script-modules/. HTH.

Answer (score 15):

Try this

```
Get-InstalledModule -Name Az* | Update-Module
```

You can add `-Force` after `Update-Module`, so you won't be prompted with stuff like an untrusted repository every single module.

Comment: I am getting `Update-Module: Module 'Az' was not installed by using Install-Module, so it cannot be updated.`

Answer (score 4):

You could try this script, which I wrote a while ago. It goes through every `Az.*` module and updates to the latest version, including removing previous versions that are still installed.

```
# Go through all Az.* versions
# Use -ListAvailable to show all versions
Get-Module -Name Az.* -ListAvailable | ForEach-Object {
    $moduleName = $_.Name
    $currentVersion = [Version]$_.Version

    Write-Host "Current version $moduleName [$currentVersion]"

    # Get latest version from gallery
    $latestVersion = [Version](Find-Module -Name $moduleName).Version
    
    # Only proceed if latest version in gallery is greater than your current version
    if ($latestVersion -gt $currentVersion) {
        Write-Host "Found latest version $modulename [$latestVersion] from $($latestVersionModule.Repository)"

        # Check if latest version is already installed before updating
        $latestVersionModule = Get-InstalledModule -Name $moduleName -RequiredVersion $latestVersion -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($null -eq $latestVersionModule) {
            Write-Host "Updating $moduleName Module from [$currentVersion] to [$latestVersion]"
            Update-Module -Name $moduleName -RequiredVersion $latestVersion -Force
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "No update needed, $modulename [$latestVersion] already exists"
        }

        # Uninstall outdated version
        Write-Host "Uninstalling $moduleName [$currentVersion]"
        Uninstall-Module -Name $moduleName -RequiredVersion $currentVersion -Force
    }

    # Otherwise we already have most up to date version
    else {
        Write-Host "$moduleName already up to date"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Update-Module Az -Force
```

All the individual modules are dependencies of the Az module. So this should do the trick.

Add -Verbose if you want to track progress.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the Az PowerShell module is formally documented, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps#update-the-azure-powershell-module). While the existing answers are accurate and helpful, there is some nuance that may be helpful to note.

> To update any PowerShell module, you should use the same method used
> to install the module. For example, if you originally used
> Install-Module, then you should use Update-Module to get the latest
> version. If you originally used the MSI package, then you should
> download and install the new MSI package.
>
> The PowerShellGet cmdlets cannot update modules that were installed
> from an MSI package. MSI packages do not update modules that were
> installed using PowerShellGet. If you have any issues updating using
> PowerShellGet, then you should reinstall, rather than update.
> Reinstalling is done the same way as installing. Ensure you use the
> Force parameter with Install-Module when reinstalling.

Comment: While the callout is much appreciated, along with not wanting to provide a duplicate answer I feel a rough 50,000 foot view of the steps in the "formal documentation" link would still improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This article provides complete detailed information and steps on e Azure Az PowerShell module: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-5.7.0
If you are looking for specific service module check in the **reference** section

Comment: This equates to a link only answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Update all modules

Get-Module -Name Az.* -ListAvailable | ForEach-Object { Update-Module -Name $_.Name -Force }

## Uninstall old versions

Get-Module -Name Az.* -ListAvailable |
Where-Object { $*.Version -ne (Get-InstalledModule -Name $*.Name).Version } |
ForEach-Object { Uninstall-Module -Name $*.Name -RequiredVersion $*.Version -Force }